# use custom image for facebook login button

Tags: javascript, facebook

So yes I'm new to this and i done research and i heard it can be done by triggering FB.login func by JavaScript. can any body tell me how to do this proper way, example would be great, i saw this page http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.login/ but i can't make anything out of it!

what i want is when user clicks the image a popup should be opened to request permissions just as clicking fb button. Thank you so much.

Comment: Have you created an App on the Dashboard yet?

Comment: i'm using the php sdk now it's working fine i want to know how to use custom image

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can do this

```
<img src="myimage.png" onclick="FB.login()" />
```

FB library should be loaded of course

Answer (score 0):

You need to load the [JavaScript SDK](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript) in order for the FB.login (or any FB.* functions) to work in javascript. Once you've done that, you can bind your FB.login code however you want to your image (e.g. using an `onclick` attribute or using js/jquery to bind to the `click` event). Let me know if you have any questions..